# How to get a list based on previous selection in angular2

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    name: string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
    { name: 'STWX1' },
    { name: 'STWX2' },
    { name: 'STWX3' },
    { name: 'STWX4' }
];

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div style="display: inline-block; width = 200px; ">
            <ul class="heroes">
                <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)"
                    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
                    <p>{{hero.name}}</p>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </div>

       <div style="display: inline-block; width = 200px; ">
           <div *ngIf="selectedHero">
               <div ng-switch on="selectedHero.name">
                   <div ng-switch-when="one">
                       <ul class="heroes">
                           <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect1(hero)"
                               [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero1">
                               <p>{{selectedHero.name}}</p>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div style="display: inline-block; width = 200px; ">
           <div *ngIf="selectedHero1">
               <ul class="heroes">
                   <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
                       <p>{{hero.name}}</p>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>

       <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
   ,
   styles: [...]
})

export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular1';
    testRequestId = '3224';
    heroes = HEROES;
    selectedHero: Hero;
    selectedHero1: Hero;

    goToDivClick() {
        return HEROES;
    }

    onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }

    onSelect1(hero: Hero): void {
        this.selectedHero1 = hero;
    }
}
```

I am trying as mentioned above to populate a list based on what was selected earlier. If a select text 'STWX1', then only I want to get inside switch case, but its not currently happening. Please let me know what needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using incorrect syntax.

You must use `[ngSwitch]` and `*ngSwitchCase / *ngSwitchDefault`:

```
...
<div [ngSwitch]="selectedHero.name">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'one'">
...
```

See [**`docs`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html)

Comment: <div [ngSwitch]="selectedHero.name">
    <div *ngSwitchCase='STWX1'>

Comment: I added like this, now on selecting STWX1, nothing happens. Can you please let me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Will "selectedHero.name" give me the name of the hero selected.

Comment: Try `*ngSwitchCase="'STWX1'"`. Note the **INNER** quote.

Comment: @test I'm glad that It helped :)

Comment: Can you accept the answer? Just click on green tick.